# How can I use WIF to secure access to static files?

Tags: security, iis-7.5, wif, claims-based-identity

I have a folder of jpg images on an IIS server & we need to secure them so that only people with a particular permission can view them.  We have implemented WIF based STS (not AD) for authentication on other parts of the site & I would like to be able to use a particular claim on a WIF authenticated user to allow them read access to these image files through IIS (IIS 7).

I could write a custom handler to do the check but I would rather not have to pass the static files through the .net pipeline.  We have looked at the [C2WTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517278.aspx) option but that seems to be hard coded to use the UPN claim which our STS doesn't provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not use the location tag in the web.config specifying that particular folder and then inside it, use something like:

```
<allow roles="Viewer"/>
<deny users="*"/>
```